# where is the autoload? trying to unit test

Tags: zend-framework2

i am following a getting started [tutorial](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html) on zend framework 2, in [one of the topics](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/unit-testing.html) it suggests using tests, [the code](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/unit-testing.html#your-first-controller-test) it suggests is:

```
namespace ApplicationTest\Controller;

use ApplicationTest\Bootstrap;
use Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\TreeRouteStack as HttpRouter;
use Application\Controller\IndexController;
use Zend\Http\Request;
use Zend\Http\Response;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;
use Zend\Mvc\Router\RouteMatch;
use PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase;

class IndexControllerTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    protected $controller;
    protected $request;
    protected $response;
    protected $routeMatch;
    protected $event;

    protected function setUp()
    {
        $serviceManager = Bootstrap::getServiceManager();
        $this->controller = new IndexController();
        $this->request    = new Request();
        $this->routeMatch = new RouteMatch(array('controller' => 'index'));
        $this->event      = new MvcEvent();
        $config = $serviceManager->get('Config');
        $routerConfig = isset($config['router']) ? $config['router'] : array();
        $router = HttpRouter::factory($routerConfig);

        $this->event->setRouter($router);
        $this->event->setRouteMatch($this->routeMatch);
        $this->controller->setEvent($this->event);
        $this->controller->setServiceLocator($serviceManager);
    }
    public function testIndexActionCanBeAccessed()
    {
        $this->routeMatch->setParam('action', 'index');

        $result   = $this->controller->dispatch($this->request);
        $response = $this->controller->getResponse();

        $this->assertEquals(200, $response->getStatusCode());        

    }
}
```

as you can see there is no `__autoload($class)`.

to manually make it  work i added `include "../../Bootstrap.php";` it did solve the problem but i remember once i could get this code to work, and the tutorial doesn't seem to forget something conceptually obvious and there is no feedback about it in the Topic comments , there may be something I am missing, how would the code above probably work?

Comment: Did you create the `phpunit.xml.dist` under `zf2-tutorial/module/Application/test` as directed in the instructions? As far as I'm aware, that should include `Bootstrap.php` as long as that file's in the same folder.

Comment: yes it exists like the tutorial suggest, if you're familiar with the tutorial, i got it to work, continued the tutorial to the next test (The Album) and the [albumtest](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/routing-and-controllers.html#write-the-tests) didn't work i came back to the 1st test, and it wasn't working and the debug started :D

Comment: What is your issue now? I've followed the tutorial and it worked fine for me, although I did run in to a few problems through not following it meticulously.

Comment: @aydin: thanks but if you are suggesting me to redo all the tutorial, well that might work, but the goal is not getting it to work, (i dont want the getting started app), the goal is being able to do projects. and i will face such problems at that time, where there is no step by step tutorial available. so i will choose going a little deep and try to survive

Comment: @shampoo, not suggesting that. I just asked what your new issue was. I was stating that the tutorial works as is.

Comment: @Aydin: i guessed that i have done something wrong and the tutorial is just fine, without the code i mentioned `include "../../Bootstrap.php"; ` the code above DOESN'T WORK, why? and for a place to start i looked for `__autoload()` and no luck :| then i asked here .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working but noticed you couldn't use phpUnit's extended Request and Response objects.  These are the instructions for early 2.0 release.  At least after 2.0.7, the instructions are much different and the code is cleaner:

http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user-guide/unit-testing.html

```
<?php

namespace ApplicationTest\Controller;

use Zend\Test\PHPUnit\Controller\AbstractHttpControllerTestCase;

class IndexControllerTest extends AbstractHttpControllerTestCase
{
    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->setApplicationConfig(
            include '/path/to/application/config/test/application.config.php'
        );
        parent::setUp();
    }

    public function testIndexActionCanBeAccessed()
    {
        $this->dispatch('/');
        $this->assertResponseStatusCode(200);

        $this->assertModuleName('application');
        $this->assertControllerName('application_index');
        $this->assertControllerClass('IndexController');
        $this->assertMatchedRouteName('home');
    }
}
```

In this example testing is carried out by extending Zend's controller test case, which was the way controller tests were carried out with zf1.